# Cancel a stored procedure call when using Spring

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

The `java.sql.Statement` interface provides a [cancel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#cancel%28%29) method which allows to abort a database call from another thread.

However, I can't find a similar option available if I'm using Spring's [StoredProcedure](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/object/StoredProcedure.html) class to call a stored procedure.

Is there any way to achieve the cancel / abort functionality if I use Spring's StoredProcedure?

Comment: Check for jdbctemplate.call() and callablestatementcallback?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the conventional approach because till now I never came across this scenario :( .

As an option you can extend StoredProcedure class and can write your own implementation of `cancel()` there .